# Windows cannot find 'move'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Why do I get this error? I am just trying to move files around using Chocolatey's sudo package:

```
PS C:\Users\samue> sudo MOVE .\project_e_commerce\paypal 'C:\Program Files\Go\src\'
PS C:\Users\samue> sudo MOVE .\project_e_commerce\paypal 'C:\Program Files\Go\src\paypal'
PS C:\Users\samue> sudo MOVE .\project_e_commerce\paypal 'C:\Program Files\Go\src\paypal'
PS C:\Users\samue> sudo move .\project_e_commerce\paypal 'C:\Program Files\Go\src\paypal'
PS C:\Users\samue> sudo move .\project_e_commerce\paypal 'C:\Program Files\Go\src\paypal'
```

All these gave the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Windows never had `move` as a standalone program – it only exists as a *built-in* command in Cmd, and separately as an alias to Move-Item within PowerShell.

You would need to run it as `cmd /c move…` for the Cmd version or `powershell -Command {move…}` for the PowerShell one.

Answer (score 0):

Program Files is a secured folder. That is most likely why the move failed.

Find a more neutral location for your Project Files:  My Documents or you can set up a Project Folder in C:\Program Data or even C:\Projects.

Then try moving with the Command Prompt